# Writing a query to find the following result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Employees Table:

```
EmpID EmpName    
----- --------------    
1     John Torres    
2     Irina Williams
```

Payroll Week Table:

```
WeekID EmpID WeekStart  WeekEnd    
------ ----- ---------- ----------    
1      1     11-20-2011 11-26-2011
2      2     11-27-2011 12-03-2011
3      1     11-27-2011 12-03-2011
```

Employee Visits Table:

```
ID EmpID VisitDate  StartTime EndTime Earningcode    
-- ----- ---------- --------- ------- -----------    
1  1     11-20-2011 10:00     12:00   Sat-Sun1    
2  1     11-21-2011 13:30     16:00   Mon-Fri1    
3  1     11-22-2011 14:00     15:00   Mon-Fri1    
4  1     11-24-2011 10:00     14:00   Mon-Fri1    
5  1     11-25-2011 13:30     16:00   Mon-Fri1    
6  1     11-26-2011 14:00     15:00   Sat-Sun1    
7  2     11-27-2011 09:00     11:00   Sat-Sun1    
8  2     11-28-2011 07:00     12:00   Mon-Fri1    
9  2     11-29-2011 09:00     11:00   Mon-Fri1    
10 2     12-03-2011 07:00     12:00   Sat-Sun1
```

Expected Results

```
RecordType EmpID EmpName        WeekStart  WeekEnd    Earning code  Hours
---------- ----- -------------- ---------- ---------- ------------  -----
H          1     John Torres    11-20-2011 11-26-2011         
D                                                     Sat-Sun1     3.00
D                                                     Mon-Fri1     10.00
H          2     Irina Williams 11-27-2011 12-03-2011
D                                                     Sat-Sun1     7.00
D                                                     Mon-Fri1     7.00
```

Comment: The H and D denote what, sorry?

Comment: Two questions, what have you tried? No one wants to do your complete work. :-) What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hello Luke ,The H and D denote the Header and Details respectively.

Comment: Hello Ionic, I have tried using joining the 3 tables using then using the group by rollup command but it did not help.And i am using SQL server

Comment: Fixed code formatting to make the question more readible

Comment: ;With AB as
( 
Select empid, earningcode
from EmployeeVisits 
group by rollup (empid,earningcode) 
),
EF as
(
select e.empid,e.empname,AB.earningcode
from employees e join AB on e.empid=ab.empid
)
select EF.empid,EF.empname,p.weekstart,p.weekend,EF.earningcode
from PayrollWeek p join EF on p.EmpID=EF.empid where earningcode IS NOT NULL
                                                                                                    I was able to find part of the answer but was not able to obtain the value of earning code and hours..Also the blank spaces in the column is difficult to obtain..

Comment: Creating this kind of formatting is quite tricky in SQL and makes your queries quite difficult to understand / maintain. If possible, you should do the formatting into headers and details outside the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this type of formatting (with headers and details) is something that might be better to do outside the database (in a reporting application forinstance) it's certainly possible to do on the server too.

One way to do this is to union two different queries; one for the headers and one for the details:

```
select RecordType, EmpID, EmpName, Week, WeekStart, WeekEnd, Earningcode, Hours 
from 
(
    select 'H' as RecordType, e.EmpID, EmpName, datepart(wk, WeekStart) as Week, WeekStart, WeekEnd, null as Earningcode, null as Hours
    from Employees e
    join PayrollWeek pw on pw.EmpID = e.EmpID
    join EmployeeVisits ev on e.EmpID = ev.EmpID and ev.VisitDate between pw.WeekStart and pw.WeekEnd
    group by e.EmpID, EmpName, WeekStart, WeekEnd, datepart(wk, WeekStart)
) H -- query for header rows
union all
(
    select 'D' as RecordType, ev.EmpID, null, datepart(wk, WeekStart) as WeekD, null, null, Earningcode, sum(datediff(minute, StartTime, EndTime))/60.0
    from EmployeeVisits ev
    join PayrollWeek pw on ev.VisitDate between pw.WeekStart and pw.WeekEnd and ev.EmpID = pw.EmpID
    group by ev.EmpID, Earningcode, datepart(wk, WeekStart)
) -- query for detail rows
order by EmpID, Week, RecordType desc, Earningcode desc
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e5bb/3)

Note that the Week column is only included to be able to ensure ordering.

I added some rows for week 3 for EmpId 1 for a demo and the query above would then get you this result:

```
| RecordType | EmpID |        EmpName | Week |  WeekStart |    WeekEnd | Earningcode |  Hours |
|------------|-------|----------------|------|------------|------------|-------------|--------|
|          H |     1 |    John Torres |   48 | 2011-11-20 | 2011-11-26 |      (null) | (null) |
|          D |     1 |         (null) |   48 |     (null) |     (null) |    Sat-Sun1 |      3 |
|          D |     1 |         (null) |   48 |     (null) |     (null) |    Mon-Fri1 |     10 |
|          H |     1 |    John Torres |   49 | 2011-11-27 | 2011-12-03 |      (null) | (null) |
|          D |     1 |         (null) |   49 |     (null) |     (null) |    Mon-Fri1 |      2 |
|          H |     2 | Irina Williams |   49 | 2011-11-27 | 2011-12-03 |      (null) | (null) |
|          D |     2 |         (null) |   49 |     (null) |     (null) |    Sat-Sun1 |      7 |
|          D |     2 |         (null) |   49 |     (null) |     (null) |    Mon-Fri1 |      7 |
```

Comment: Hello JPW ,,if it is not too much fuss... can you tell me how did you go about creating this query.. and how did you go about applying the condition? ..it would really help me to know about the do's and don't's when creating such complex queries..

Comment: @Vicky Sure. I've done queries like this before and used experience, but in general my approach is to try to break down the problem in smaller parts and solve each small problem first and the join the different parts together to create the final solution. In this particular case it meant creating one query for the header part and one for the details and then find a working way to join the results together.